# Failure when deploying MVC 5 web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, runtime-error

I kept getting this error after deploying my MVC 5 Web Application :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

After googling around, I found that the reason is the Bin folder lacks of System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll file, then I go to look in the Bin folder of my project, but I also can't find it, but it appears in the References section :

[image]

Now I have no idea how to solve this problem, any help is greatly appreciated!

P/s : the web application is running fine on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking the reference -> Properties, and set `CopyLocal = true` . That should put the dll in your bin folder (and thus be included in the deployment as well). Hope that helps!

Comment: I found it too, forgot to come back here. Thanks anyway :)